# Notepad++ regex find XML attribute containing a substring

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to find XML tag which has a attribute which does contain a certain value in their string. For example you have this XML:

```
<situation xsi:type="..." id="PK_1243f_TESTING_093891">
        .....
</situation>
```

In this example you see that the id has 'TESTING' in it. But there are also situations without this in their id like this:

```
<situation xsi:type="..." id="PK_1932z_093716">
        .....
</situation>
```

Which can be found by this regex:

```
<situation xsi:type="([^\"]*)\" id="((?!TESTING).)*"(?:(?!</situation>).)+</situation>
```

What changes need to be made in the regex above to find the situation with 'TESTING' in their id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `<situation xsi:type="([^"]*)" id="[^"]*TESTING[^"]*"(?:(?!</situation>).)+</situation>`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<situation xsi:type="           # literally
([^"]*)                         # group 1, 0 or more non "
"                               # quote
id="                            # literally
[^"]*                           # 0 or more non "
TESTING                         # literally
[^"]*                           # 0 or more non "
"                               # quote
(?:(?!</situation>).)+          # 1 or more any character, but never </situation>
</situation>                    # end tag
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]